# Backbone serious drawback

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Consider following example:

http://jsfiddle.net/FxX7v/1/

```
Zoo = Backbone.Model.extend({
    validate: function() {
        console.log('val');
        return "error";
    },
    url: '/save/'
});

var artis = new Zoo( { name: 'Artis' } );

console.log(artis.get( 'name' ) );

artis.save({name:'Artis2'})

console.log( artis.get( 'name' ) );
```

If you try to save changes to a model, but validation fails.

But you can see in the example that data is changed in the model.

Is this really a drawback or I am missing something?

Comment: This is not a question?

Comment: It's up to you how you want things to work. If you'd avoid changing the model, go with @David F's approach and call set with `{ validate: true }` and then `save` if validation was successful. But you may want to keep the model changed, and allow the user to cancel editing and revert the model using the `previousAttributes` function? http://backbonejs.org/#Model-previousAttributes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data will change in this example because you are not forcing validation.  If you want to force validation prior to the modification of the client-side model, you must use the set method like this:

```
artis.set({name:'Artis2'}, {validate: true});
```

Comment: When calling `save`, `validate` is always called by default: http://backbonejs.org/#Model-validate

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but using set explicitly runs validation before affecting your client side model.  The validation on save occurs after the client model is modified, but before it is persisted to the server.

Comment: Yes, OK. Thought you meant that his example would not run `validate` at all.

Comment: Omg, I was thinking same as in first comment. I think I have lost some several hours, just by this misconception.